# SharePoint PnP PowerShell Provision Comments with Modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision, office-dev-pnp

I an provisioning some modern pages from One site to another using SharePoint PnP PowerShell by Generating and Applying Provisioning Template. I am able to Provision the page with web parts but the Page Comments are not being provisioned. How to provision Page Comments along with modern page?

Below is the code I'm using:

> To generate PnP Template

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out ./mp1ppc.pnp -Handlers Pages, PageContents
```

> To apply PnP Template

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path .\mp1.pnp
```

Please let me know if I' missing anything?

Comment: Check you template for the Pages that is provisioned.
[Provisioning Schema](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/blob/master/ProvisioningSchema-2018-01.md#clientsidepage)

Comment: @brannmar I checked, The schema doesn't include Comments Enabled attribute, but since I am generating pnp file with PowerShell cmdlet it should include necessary attributes.

Comment: Which version of the schema do you use?

Comment: Version: 2.22.1801.0

Comment: Thats probably the releaseversion of the pnp powershell installation (January 2018 Release). What im asking for is the schema version for the provisioning template. Probably that is the latest which is 201801. It should have the comments enabled attribute. If not included in your template try adding it.

Comment: Oh yeah, Its January 2018 only. my bad first. But it is not having comments enabled attribute.

Comment: I tired adding it using PowerShell Commands but again no luck in that

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the PNP provisioning cmdlets are sometimes buggy, and is not yet full featured, although new features are appearing all the time.

For now, you can change the "Comments" on a modern page **after** the page has been created.

To disable the comments on a modern page called "Test.aspx":

```
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Test.aspx" -CommentsEnabled:$false
```

To enable the comments on a modern page called "Test.aspx":

```
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Test.aspx" -CommentsEnabled:$true
```

Please note that the Powershell output labels the property "*CommentsDisabled*", but the cmdlet switch is "*CommentsEnabled*".

For more information, search the documentation for "[Get-PnPClientSidePage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpclientsidepage?view=sharepoint-ps)" and "[Set-PnPClientSidePage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpclientsidepage?view=sharepoint-ps)"

For the record, I am using the March 2018 version of PnP PowerShell.

[image: Set-PnPClientSidePage]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the engine did not have support for disabling comments on moderns pages at the time of this question. This is now supported according to the update notes for [May 2018 update](https://dev.office.com/blogs/pnp-may-2018-update)

> Added CommentsOnSitePagesDisabled property on web settings element in the provisioning engine.